# "apply map vector" idiom - How happens to be 2 functions?

Tags: clojure

Here is a sample from my mini code where I copied from clojure docs site.

```
(apply map vector (vec jpgList))
```

I guess map and vector are both functions, but apply takes only one function. How come in here apply takes two functions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read the documentation of `apply`:

```
user=> (doc apply)
-------------------------
clojure.core/apply
([f args] [f x args] [f x y args] [f x y z args] [f a b c d & args])
  Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending intervening arguments to args.
nil
```

So, `(apply map vector (vec jpgList))` corresponds to `f x args`, so `map` will be applied to the the function `vector`, followed by the elements of `(vec jpgList)`. Unlike Haskell, Clojure's `map` supports multiple collections to operate on. `(vec jpgList)` presumably is a nested vector, or list, like in the following example:

```
user=> (apply map vector [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]])
([1 4] [2 5] [3 6])
```

What happened is, every element produced by `map` is the vector of each nth element of the elements of the nested vector. This function is also known as `transpose` in matrix operations.

Answer (score 5):

`apply` accepts a function and its arguments. If called with more than two arguments, the middle arguments will be added as scalar arguments (like using partial). See [the documentation for `apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply)

In other words, all four of these are the same:

```
(apply (partial map vector) [[1 2 3 4] "abcd"])
(apply map [vector [1 2 3 4] "abcd"])
(apply map vector [[1 2 3 4] "abcd"])
(map vector [1 2 3 4] "a b c d")
```

All will return `([1 \a] [2 \b] [3 \c] [4 \d])`.

Answer (score 2):

Only `map` is being 'applied'. However the first argument to `map` is always itself a function. In this case `vector` is being prepended to the the sequence of arguments produced by (vec jpgList). `vector` here is not a second function being applied, it is the first argument in the sequence to which `map` is applied together with the rest.

You will see this idiom often when applying any higher order function that itself takes a function as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
user=> (let [n1 1
  #_=>       n2 2
  #_=>       n-coll [n1 n2]]
  #_=>   (=
  #_=>    (apply + 999 n-coll)
  #_=>    (+ 999 n1 n2)))
true
```

'apply' applies + to the argument list formed by prepending 999 to n-coll. If you substitute map for + and vector for 999 when the collection in question is made of vectors:

```
user=> (let [r1 [1 2 3]
  #_=>       r2 [4 5 6]
  #_=>       r-coll [r1 r2]]
  #_=>   (=
  #_=>    (apply map vector r-coll)
  #_=>    (map vector r1 r2)))
true
```